# gridview width working in design view but not in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I am using Asp.net grid View . My problem is that when i am changing width of gridview it is working in design mode of visual studio 2012 but when i browse it is not working . Here is my code.

```
    <asp:Content ID="main" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="cart">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >

        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="..." DataField="....."  />
             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="..." DataField="...."  />
             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="..." DataField=".."  />
             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" DataField="prod_desc" />
             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Category" DataField="prod_ctg_id"  />

        </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>
  </div>
</asp:Content>
```

here is my master page code:

```
 <div class="col-lg-10 col-mg-10 col-md-offset-1";">
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="cart">
       </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
       </div>
```

This is css

```
#GridView1 {
width:100% ;
margin:0px;
height:400px;

}
```

I am using bootstrap and css files

```
 <link href="Content/Bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I have tryed a lot ,  I also delete browser cache but still not working.Thanks in advance.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an open <div> to match the closing one at the bottom of the markup you posted.

Comment: in actual code  open div exist but i missed here.

Comment: Depending on what you have for the classes for the div surrounding the ContentPlaceHolder, it may limit how wide the gridview can be.  The 100% width setting for the gridview will set the grid to take up the entire space as defined by the class of the div above it.

Comment: agreed , my problem solved by removing masterpage file link , i have developed the whole page again and did not link with master page.